# Dealing playing cards to four arrays

Tags: c

when I am trying to deal 52 card to four players using structure, The code works but the problem is in output it got some mistake:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    char *value;
    char *type;
}card;


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, r;
    char name[4][9] = {{"diamonds"},{"clubs"},{"hearts"},{"spades"}};
    char num[13][6] = {{"ace"},{"two"},{"three"},{"four"},{"five"},{"six"},{"seven"},{"eight"},{"nine"},{"ten"},{"jack"},{"queen"},{"king"}};
    
    card c[52];
    card temp;
    card player1[13], player2[13], player3[13], player4[13];
    
    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++){
        c[i].type = name[i % 4];
        c[i].value = num[i % 13];
    }
    
    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++){
    r= rand() % 52;
    temp = c[i];
    c[i] = c[r];
    c[r] = temp;
        
    }
    
    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++){
        switch(i+1 % 4){
            case 0:
                player1[i].type= c[i].type;
                player1[i].value= c[i].value;
                break;
            case 1:
                player2[i].type= c[i].type;
                player2[i].value= c[i].value;
                break;
            case 2:
                player3[i].type= c[i].type;
                player3[i].value= c[i].value;
                break;
            default:
                player4[i].type= c[i].type;
                player4[i].value= c[i].value;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Player 1 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player1[i].type, player1[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Player 2 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player2[i].type, player2[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Player 3 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player3[i].type, player3[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Player 4 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player4[i].type, player4[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

output:
Player 1
hearts nine
diamonds king
hearts ten
diamonds ten
spades jack
clubs king
hearts four
spades eight
spades king
clubs jack
spades two
diamonds jack
hearts jack

Player 2
spades six
hearts queen
diamonds ace
spades five
diamonds six
hearts seven
clubs eight
clubs seven
spades ace
hearts three
hearts king
diamonds two
clubs six

Player 3
spades three
diamonds seven
clubs queen
hearts six
hearts five
diamonds three
spades nine
clubs three
spades queen
clubs ace
clubs two
diamonds four
hearts ace

Player 4
à└ëD$@ï╪☼ê°♥ (null)
(null) (null)
hearts two
hearts eight
diamonds nine
clubs five
spades seven
clubs nine
spades four
clubs ten
diamonds eight
diamonds queen
clubs four

It got in player 4 null and strange characters, any solution please.

Comment: Deal loop `for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++)` what happens to e.g., `player1[i]`? How big are the player arrays? (hint: not `52`)

Comment: one player array contain 13 elements

Comment: What happens when `i > 12`? (hint: *Undefined Behavior* caused by writing beyond your array bounds)

Comment: `switch(i+1 % 4)` ==> If you must ... `switch((i+1) % 4)` and add a `default` case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation that does what you asked:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PLAYERS_NUM 4
#define CARDS_PER_PLAYER 13
#define NAMES_NUM 4
#define VALUES_NUM 13
#define TOTAL_CARDS NAMES_NUM*VALUES_NUM

typedef struct {
    char *value;
    char *type;
} card;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    unsigned int i, j, r;
    char *name[NAMES_NUM] = {"diamonds", "clubs", "hearts", "spades"};
    char *num[VALUES_NUM] = {"ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack",
                             "queen", "king"};

    // Initialize pile.
    card cards[TOTAL_CARDS];
    for (i = 0; i < NAMES_NUM; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < VALUES_NUM; j++) {
            cards[(i * VALUES_NUM) + j] = (card) {name[j], num[i]};
        }
    }

    card tmp;
    // Shuffle pile.
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_CARDS; i++) {
        r = rand() % TOTAL_CARDS;
        tmp = cards[r];
        cards[r] = cards[i];
        cards[i] = tmp;
    }

    card players[PLAYERS_NUM][CARDS_PER_PLAYER];

    // Deal cards.
    for (i = 0; i < PLAYERS_NUM; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < CARDS_PER_PLAYER; j++) {
            players[i][j] = cards[i * CARDS_PER_PLAYER + j];
        }
    }

    // Printing.
    for (i = 0; i < PLAYERS_NUM; i++) {
        printf("Player %d\n", i);
        for (j = 0; j < CARDS_PER_PLAYER; j++) {
            printf("%s %s\n", players[i][j].type, players[i][j].value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A couple of points:

- You didn't include `#include <stdlib.h>`.
- You didn't deal the cards, there could have been duplicated cards, this implementation shuffles the cards and deals them without repetitions.
- You don't need 4 arrays to hold the players, a two-dimensional array is better (also later to pass on to functions).
- The code can look cleaner if you use defined values instead of repeating them over and over again, that way they can also be changed in one place and take effect everywhere.
- You don't need to define the names and values' sizes, if you're not planning on changing them, they will be a static const string, so just defines as `char *`, that way you don't need to find the longest string, and allocate useless data.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs in your deal loop when you loop `for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++)` setting `player1[i]`, `player2[i]`, and so on. You declare your player arrays with `13` elements. So in your loop, when `i > 12` you invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to write to the `13th` element and beyond.

To solve the problem, you need to limit your player index to `0-12` you can either use `i % 13`, e.g.

```
    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++) {
        switch (i % 4){
            case 0:
                player1[i%13] = c[i];
                break;
            case 1:
                player2[i%13] = c[i];
                break;
            case 2:
                player3[i%13] = c[i];
                break;
            default:
                player4[i%13] = c[i];
        }
    }
```

Or keep separate counters for your player indexes and increment each as the cards are dealt.
Making the changes, you would have, e.g.

```
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 0, p3 = 0, p4 = 0;
    ...
    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++) {
        switch (i % 4){
            case 0:
                player1[p1++] = c[i];
                break;
            case 1:
                player2[p2++] = c[i];
                break;
            case 2:
                player3[p3++] = c[i];
                break;
            default:
                player4[p4++] = c[i];
        }
    }
```

(**note:** you can simply assign the structs, no need for separate values. you can remove the `+1` from `switch (i % 4)`.)

Now your hands will deal without a SegFault.

Comment: Why is this the correct answer? Why use 4 different arrays? Also, there are many other issues with the code...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64982690/14273548

Comment: You can do it with my example as well, modify the code, or make the player a pointer to that index in the array, it's bad practice to have 4 arrays... @superzer101

Comment: @UriyaHarpeness Whether you use 1D arrays or 2D arrays is completely irrelevant. From a micro-optimization standpoint, a 1D array has performance advantages.

Comment: First off, on that notion you could avoid using 1D arrays as well, secondly, it takes more memory, as well as a lot less readable. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: It takes no more or no less memory -- period. Where did you come up with that? An array is a continuous block of `nelements * sizeof(type)` bytes, regardless of 1D or 2D. The difference is with a 2D array, you have the overhead of computing the offsets being done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared Player structure array size 13 but you are passing upto 52 that's why it's showing null name. You should always pass upto `<13` index in `Player` structure. To do that pass `player[i%13]` value by Mod of 13.

```
player[i%13].type= c[i].type;
player[i%13].value= c[i].value;
```

When you pass `for(i=0 ; i<52 ; i++)` your loop pass big size. Mod 13 indicate a player will take upto 12 value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef struct {
    char *value;
    char *type;
}card;


int main()
{
    int i, r;
    char name[4][9] = {{"diamonds"},{"clubs"},{"hearts"},{"spades"}};
    char num[13][6] = {{"ace"},{"two"},{"three"},{"four"},{"five"},{"six"},{"seven"},{"eight"},{"nine"},{"ten"},{"jack"},{"queen"},{"king"}};

    card c[52];
    card temp;
    card player1[13], player2[13], player3[13], player4[13];

    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++){
        c[i].type = name[i % 4];
        c[i].value = num[i % 13];
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++){
    r= rand() % 51;
    temp = c[i];
    c[i] = c[r];
    c[r] = temp;

    }
    for (i=0 ; i<52 ; i++){
        int ind=i+1;
        switch(ind % 4){
            case 0:
                player1[i%13].type= c[i].type;
                player1[i%13].value= c[i].value;
                break;
            case 1:
                player2[i%13].type= c[i].type;
                player2[i%13].value= c[i].value;
                break;
            case 2:
                player3[i%13].type= c[i].type;
                player3[i%13].value= c[i].value;
                break;
            default:
                player4[i%13].type= c[i].type;
                player4[i%13].value= c[i].value;
        }
    }

    printf("Player 1 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player1[i].type, player1[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Player 2 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player2[i].type, player2[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Player 3 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player3[i].type, player3[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Player 4 \n");
    for (i=0 ; i<13 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s\n" , player4[i].type, player4[i].value);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```